# Publicly expose a single page on an otherwise private server using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using `AuthType Basic` to restrict access to a test environment.  There's nothing sensitive there -it's just to keep spiders away.

I'd like to test a Webhook and to do so I need to expose a single page.

The start of my `.htaccess` follows:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/some_domain_dot_com/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

It is after this that the `RewriteRules` are in place so I don't think I can redirect for this specific page request.

How to I tell `.htaccess` not to request authentication for a single page only?